# Amazon S3 error- A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource.

Tags: amazon-s3

Why I got this error when I try to create a bucket in amazon S3?

[image: Amazon s3]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS Error Message: A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898057/aws-error-message-a-conflicting-conditional-operation-is-currently-in-progress)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

This error means that, the bucket was recently deleted and is queued for delete in S3. You must wait until the Bucket name is available again.

Kindly note, I received this error when my access-priviliges were blocked. 
The error means your Operation for creating new bucket at S3 is aborted.
There can be multiple reasons for this, you can check the below points for rectifying this error:

1. Is this Bucket available or is Queued for Deletion
2. Do you have adequate access privileges for this operation
3. Your Bucket Name must be unique

P.S: Edited this answer to add more details as shared by Sanity below, and his answer is more accurate with updated information.

You can view the related errors for this operation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html).
I am editing my asnwer so that correct answer posted below can be selected as correct answer to this question.

Comment: This error can occur even if you have the appropriate permissions. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16553056/2398354

Comment: AWS does not allow another account to create a bucket of the same name immediately after it is deleted, but the same account that deleted it can still create it immediately.

Comment: if you've deleted a bucket, and tried to create it with the same name but in a different region, even with the same account, you still have to wait.

Answer (score 153):

This error means that, the bucket was recently deleted and is queued for delete in S3. You must wait until the name is available again.

Comment: How long should we wait until the bucket name is available again?

Comment: @vbem It usually takes 2-3 hrs

Comment: Thanks, for me it s3 didnt allow me to create with additional suffix as well for the previously deleted bucket name

Comment: Apparently this applies especially when the bucket has been deleted in one region and you try to create it again in a different region. For example, I deleted a bucket in `us-east-1` and I had to wait more than one hour to be able to create it again in `eu-central-1`.

Comment: Thanks @JaimeHablutzel that explained my issue perfectly, after waiting an hour or so everything is working now

Answer (score 13):

Creating a [S3 bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html) and the [S3 public access block](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-block-public-access-another-layer-of-protection-for-your-accounts-and-buckets/) for a bucket at the same time will cause the error.

### Terraform example

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "allow_alb_access_bucket_elb_log" {
  bucket = local.bucket_alb_log_id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.allow_alb_access_bucket_elb_log.json
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "lb_log" {
  bucket = local.bucket_alb_log_id

  block_public_acls   = true
  block_public_policy = true
}
```

### Solution

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "lb_log" {
  bucket = local.bucket_alb_log_id

  block_public_acls   = true
  block_public_policy = true

  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # To avoid OperationAborted: A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  depends_on = [
    aws_s3_bucket_policy.allow_alb_access_bucket_elb_log
  ]
}
```

Comment: Here is a bug report for that: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/7628

Answer (score 5):

We have also observed this error several times when we try to move bucket from one account to other. In order to achieve this you should do the following :

1. Backup content of the S3 bucket you want to move.
2. Delete S3 bucket on the account.
3. Wait for 1/2 hours
4. Create a bucket with the same name in another account
5. Restore s3 bucket backup

Comment: I think currently 1/2 hour won't be enough. For me it was 1-2 hours

Answer (score 1):

I received this error running a `terraform apply` with the error:

> Error: error creating public access block policy for S3 bucket
>   (bucket-name): OperationAborted: A conflicting
>   conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource.
>   Please try again.
>           status code: 409, request id: 30B386F1FAA8AB9C, host id: M8flEj6+ncWr0174ftzHd74CXBjhlY8Ys70vTyORaAGWA2rkKqY6pUECtAbouqycbAZs4Imny/c=

It said to "please try again" which I did and it worked the second time. It seems there wasn't enough wait time when provisioning the initial resource with Terraform.

Answer (score 1):

the deleted s3 bucket is queued, and the name would be available in the next 2hrs

Answer (score 0):

To fully resolve this error, I inserted a 5 second sleep between multiple requests. There is nothing else that I had to do.