# AWS S3 Presign URL generation throwing 409 Conflicting Conditional Operation Exception

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm trying to generate S3 Presign URLs for `PUT` in a multi-threaded application, and intermittently it is throwing `AmazonS3Exception` with `409` error code,and message `A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource. Please try again`.

I have verified the s3 key for each thread, and those are unique.

Can anyone help me in understanding this exception.

Comment: See also [AWS Error Message: A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898057/aws-error-message-a-conflicting-conditional-operation-is-currently-in-progress)

Comment: @lexicore I saw that post, but in my case I'm using unique keys and just generating presign urls for PUT with 24hrs validity (no actual uploads are happening, which will be handled in a separate process later). so I couldn't relate my issue with above question.