# Unable to create 5 buckets in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have following code:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "create_5_buckets" {
  count         = "${length(var.name)}"
  bucket        = "${var.name[count.index]}"
  acl           = "private"
  region        = "us-east-2"
  force_destroy = "true"

  versioning {
    enabled    = "true"
    mfa_delete = "false"
  }
}
```

I am using terraform version .12. It keeps on running and gives me following error:

Error creating S3 bucket: Error creating S3 bucket name-a, retrying: OperationAborted: A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource. Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with the code.

```
provider "aws" {
  region                  = "us-east-2"
  shared_credentials_file = "/root/.aws/credentials"
  profile                 = "default"
}

variable name {
 default=["demo-123.com","demo-124.com","demo-125.com"]
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket" "create_5_buckets" {
  count         = "${length(var.name)}"
  bucket        = "${var.name[count.index]}"
  acl           = "private"
  region        = "us-east-2"
  force_destroy = "true"

  versioning {
    enabled    = "true"
    mfa_delete = "false"
 }
}
```

Code seems perfectly fine to me and running well, this error is not something with terraform.

It is related to AWS error [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html)there could be some synchronization time after deleting the S3 bucket need to try after sometime.

> It could be duplicate of [AWS Error Message: A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898057/aws-error-message-a-conflicting-conditional-operation-is-currently-in-progress/16553056#16553056)